# How can i use count function with autoincrement?

Tags: php, auto-increment

I am working on a php situation that i have. What it should do is like. each product has a unique id value. if the product id is posted throught submit button, A count action should be activited to count the number of time that product id is posted, so increment.

I hope i exposed the situaation clearly. This is the way i thought doing it, but can't get it work:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $do = count($_POST['id']);

  echo $do;

  if ($do > 1)
 {

  $i= $do+1;

   echo $i;
 }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>

<head>

<title>test</title>

  </head>


<body>
        <div class="holder">


 <div class="im">

 <img src="session-test/images/orange-juice.jpg" />

  <p>bestorange-juice</p>


<form method="post" action="sessiontest.php">

<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="2" />

<input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="25" />

<input type="submit" value="send value" name="submit" id="submit" />

   </form>

   </div>


<div class="im">

 <img src="session-test/images/milkshake.jpg" />

  <p>bestorange-juice</p>
<form method="post" action="sessiontest.php">

<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="3" />

<input type="hidden" id="prrice" name="price" value="1" />

<!--<input type="text" id="prodQty" name="prodQty" value="1" size="1"/>-->

<input type="submit" value="send value" name="submit" id="submit" />

   </form>

   </div>
</div>   
 </body>


  </html>
```

Comment: The way that you are doing it will just add one to the id not count how many times it has been submitted. Are you needing to count one user just while their on the page or will you want to have it count for all users?

Comment: If you want to keep a count of how many times someone posts to that page you will need to use an outside source to store your incremental count. All your variables are going to be overwritten every time some one loads the page. I would create I database table and store the post id  in one column and the count in another column and check if the post id is in the database table and if it is add one to  the count it if not add it to the data base and set the count =1

Answer (score 0):

If I assume the value in the hidden input #id is the times users vote the product:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $do = count($_POST['id']);
  echo $do++;
}
```

If I assume it incorrectly I don't understand what you want to do, sincerly.

Comment: As @CameronSpanos says, you need to create a database table or column in your Entity (depends of your structure database) to save the result of the counter.

My answer it works only if you have something like this working.